# In wpf, is there a way to change the inkcanvas background colour in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, rgb, inkcanvas

I'm making a small paint program using wpf's inkcanvas and I've been trying to change the background colour in the c# code so the user will be able change it while it's running by adding RGB values.
Could anyone give me an example or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please read [This Article](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). It is going to help you a lot in resolving current and future problems.

Comment: Good point, I've changed my description, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of pre-made colors to use, which can be access as such

```
myInkCanvas.Background = Brushes.GhostWhite;
```

To adjust to your updated question

```
int r, g, b; 
//set r,g,b to something
myInkCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)r, (byte)b, (byte)b));
```

And for fun, if you have a hex string

```
myInkCanvas.Background = (Brush) new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter().ConvertFromString("#FFFFFF90");
```

With separate hex string

```
myInkCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0xff, 0x90));
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing it with hex, thanks.

Comment: @AGJM13 No problem. However, if you are dealing with integers internally I wouldn't string them together and convert that... That would be unnecessary.... mostly just if you were reading from a string, or getting it from the user

Answer (score 1):

```
theInkCanvas.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b));
```